# How to handle this simple IO exception in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Deal all:

In the below code, `getDirectoryContents dir` may fail. For example the `dir` might not exists. How to catch this and throw a meaningful message to the user? I know that IO exception handling has been asked many times but i still can't find a simple way to do this.

```
walk :: FilePath -> IO()
walk dir = do
    contentsFullPath <- getDirectoryContents dir >>= removeDotFile >>= getFullPath
    dirList <- filterM doesDirectoryExist contentsFullPath
    fileList <- filterM doesFileExist contentsFullPath
    forM_ fileList processFile >> forM_ dirList walk            
    where
        removeDotFile = return . filter (`notElem` ["..", "."])
        getFullPath = return . zipWith ( </> ) (repeat dir)
        processFile = getFileSize
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the module [`Control.Exception`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Exception.html) with it's host of functions for catching/handling exceptions,

in your case

```
handler :: IOException -> IO [FilePath]
handler = undefined

walk :: FilePath -> IO()
walk dir = do
    contentsFullPath <- handle handler $ 
                          getDirectoryContents dir
                          >>= removeDotFile
                          >>= getFullPath
    ...
```

`handle` is just the same as `catch` except the arguments are swapped. It takes an `IO` computation which might throw an exception, a handler for some type of exception, and runs the computation, catching that particular type of exception.

Since you might not be able to return an appropriate list of `FilePath`s, you may want to catch the exception higher up, with something more like `walk dir = handle handler $ do ...` and then you can simply have a handler of type `IOException -> IO ()`.

Since in this case we're interested in `IO` exceptions, that what we use.