# How to ignore exception or Error and continue IO actions in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    res <- try (mapM_ (callProcess "pandoc") [["--help"],["-eoc"],["-exois"],["--help"]]) :: IO (Either SomeException ())
    case res of
        Right a -> print "done"
        Left e -> print "error"
```

in the above code, some of the argument for the command `pandoc` are wrong and pandoc will throw errors. but I want my code to continue without stopping there and finish the mapM_

What Exception handling should I use?

The error I have is:

```
    pandoc: unrecognized option `-e'
Try pandoc --help for more information.
"error"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle this simple IO exception in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188154/how-to-handle-this-simple-io-exception-in-haskell)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `try`ing your best to do a whole block of commands, have a block of commands that each `try` their best. Change `try (mapM_ foo bar)` into `mapM_ (try . foo) bar`.